# An extra margin is added when used \begin{center}

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

In my MWE
I use `\frame{\includegraphics....}` to find what happens

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}



\begin{center}
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{13-1.JPG}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

My problem is

[image]

And in fact the picture has no white margin
[image]

How can I solve this problem
Thanks

**According to a helper @David suggestion The follow is original picture**
http://s730.photobucket.com/user/ytyyutianyun/media/13-1.jpg.html
To get original picture, right click is not the right thing. (because it is smaller).
In the right side of the page, there is a `download` press-button.

Comment: While `\frame` exists, it's not documented; what are you using it for?

Comment: @egreg Actually, in my document,there is no `\frame{\includegraphics....} ` but `\includegraphics`. The reason I give is to show clearly why it doesn't center when I use `\begin{center}`. And I think it can help others know that in fact {jpg+ white margin} is be used to center in this MWE rather than just the {jpg}.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle First answer is xelatex+texlive2014+winedt+windows

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Second answer is I use xelatex instead. But You remind me. I reexamine the tex. I found the picture which is problematic is "JPG" and when I transfer into "png". It is surprise OK.

Comment: @ytyyutianyun It may be an issue with that specific file, as I say if you can make it available we could try it, otherwise there is possibly not much we can say, it's supposed to work (my comment above implying xelatex can't include jpg was incorrect)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, I edit the question by adding the original picture. Thanks

Comment: I simplified the example to remove dependency on CJK fonts, and can confirm that with xetex the result is exactly as you show. With pdflatex (which can be used on the simplified file) there is no extra space. Possibly there is some internal structure in that jpeg that is not understood by xetex when determining the size. This is beyond my knowledge it may be worth raising it as a bug report on the xetex list.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle When I submit this bug, I find one person had same problem 3 months ago. [https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/99/](https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/99/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in xetex or dvipdfmx image size reading code (or a problem in that jpg file that does not trouble pdftex).

If I use the simplified example with `pdflatex` it works with no extra space. It also helpfully shows in the log what size it thinks the image is. With `pdflatex` the log shows

```
<13-1.JPG, id=1, 626.34pt x 295.1025pt>
```

If we tell xetex that the file is that size (using `bp` units for points)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\frame{\includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth,natwidth=626.34bp, natheight=295.1025bp]{13-1.JPG}}



\end{document}
```

Then the inclusion works with a tight bounding box in `xelatex` as well:

[image]